# @parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'process' from './node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, parcel

I'm working on a project and when I try to run parcel dev or build command it outputs the following error:

```
    × Build failed.
    @parcel/core: Failed to resolve 'process' from './node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js'
    
      D:\Workspace\Front-End\Apps\RISC-Aswan\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.esm2017.js:5741:38
        5740 |         return t.store(e);
      > 5741 |     }
      >      |      ^
        5742 |     // visible for testing
        5743 |     /** Parse User Agent to determine iOS version. Returns -1 if not found. */
```

It was working before and now I don't know the cause of the problem. I tried to delete node__modules folder and run npm install but nothing changes.

I have the following imports in the script file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

the second line importing the firestore is what causing the problem, commenting it leads to everthing works fine.

Here's a photo with the terminal message and the esm2017.js file
[image: Error Message]

My package.json dependecies:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "parcel": "^2.2.1",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.18"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^9.6.6",
        "vanilla-hamburger": "^0.2.3"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `package.json` you are defining `parcel` to be the higher version **compatible** with `2.2.1`:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "parcel": "^2.2.1"
     // Rest of packages
```

Currently there is an [issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7704) in the GitHub repository for `parcel` regarding this problem with Firebase. While that issue shows your exact error message, the general issue to keep track of is [this open issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7697), since this problem affects libraries other than Firebase. Something you could do is to avoid using an affected version of `parcel` (2.3.1 as far as I see on the issues), or keep track of the issue to update to a fixed version when it releases.

**EDIT (2/23/2021):**

It seems that both GitHub issues are now closed with the release of Parcel `2.3.2`. I tested building a React project with Parcel and Firebase using version `2.3.1`, and I encountered the exact same error as you. Updating to `2.3.2` solved the issue completely on my end without any other change of dependencies. Just in case anyone comes across this thread later on.

Comment: I read the issue and done all the suggested solutions with no success. I used "alias": {"process": "false"} in the package.json file, manually installed process package, used parcel src/index.html command and removed the source in the package.json file and updated to node 16.14.0 (was 16.13.1)  but nothing of them worked

Comment: I edited my answer since Parcel version `2.3.2` has been released to address this issue.

Answer (score 4):

for some reason modifying alias to the following worked in dev and build

```
"alias": {
    "process": {
        "global": "{}"
    }
}
```

Here's the other suggested workaround i tried mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7697)

- used alias in my package.json file

```
     "alias": {
            "process": "false"
        }
```

- manually installed process package

```
    "dependencies": {
        "process": "^0.11.10",
    },
```

- updated node to `v16.14.0` instead of `v16.13.1`.
- used `parcel build ./src/index.html` and removed `"source": "./src/index.html"` in the package.json

Answer (score 0):

I was using yarn on netlify and had to do this to fix:

```
echo 'nodeLinker: node-modules' >> /opt/build/repo/.yarnrc.yml
```

Comment: the problem mentioned is solved in the then-next version of parcel, update the package if you havent. I'd also recommend using vite